# What size is this internal screw for the Macbook Air (A1466)?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, repair, third-party, 3rd-party

I just replaced the battery for my Macbook Air (A1466), but in the process I lost one of the screws (image attached). I initially ordered a standard replacement set from Amazon, but realized it may not contain the specific screw I need.

A lot of the replacement packages seem to be for the external screws. But the one I need is just this specific one. Without it my Macbook's trackpad does not register clicks (based on prior experience).

[image: missing screw directly below batery]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website [ifixit.com](http://fixit.com) has repair guides for many Apple computers, including the [from-mid-2012 A1266 MacBook Air](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Air_13%22_Mid_2012).

One of the entries for this MacBook Air is [Replace Trackpad](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2012+Trackpad+Replacement/10962). Step 10 contains this picture, showing the screw in question highlighted. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The instruction text says it is a 1.4mm T5 Torx set screw.